# Return values with JSFL script in Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash-cc, jsfl

I have a file named loader.js, and this is my code :

```
var csi=new CSInterface();

function evalScript(script, callback) {
    new CSInterface().evalScript(script, callback);
}

var docName = evalScript('fl.getDocumentDOM().name');
alert(jsfl);
```

The above code is a JSFL code to show a document name of a flash file, and i put it on a javascript file (to create a html5 extension for Flash CC). Unfortunately the variable `docName` always showing `undefined`. But if i change the code to be like this:

```
var docName = evalScript('fl.trace(fl.getDocumentDOM().name);');
```

The above code can make the variable `docName` showing my "document name" inside the output panel in flash IDE. How can i get the document name and put it on variable `docName` (if it's possible, i dont want to load any external jsfl file). Thanks for your helping, and sorry for my bad english,

Answer (score 0):

You should use the the evalScript method's callback parameter.

```
var docName;

function evalScript(script, callback) {
    new CSInterface().evalScript(script, callback);
}

evalScript('fl.getDocumentDOM().name', setName);

function setName(response) {
    docName = response;
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider a brief explanation here.   typically code only answers are not well received.  YMMV